# Code generator when machine language supports or not indirect jumps

Tags: compiler-construction

```
k = 1
if (a .eq. 10) k = 2
if (a .lt. 10) k = 3
goto (100,102,105),k
```

In this example of fortran, where k and a are integer variables, and 100, 102, and 105 valid code tags, the command goto will move the code stream to one of the 100, 102 and 105, depending on the value of the variable a. for a computed goto the intermediate code provides pointers to the command labels.

My question is: How is the code generated as the final phase of compilation when the machine language does NOT support indirect jumps and branches and how is this when the machine language supports indirect jumps and branches?

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of ways this could be done, this answer provides but a few. It really comes down to whatever capabilities are available in your architecture of choice.

First, some clarity. Let's assume the `goto` uses `k` to decide which path to jump to but, if `k` is some other value, it carries on without jumping.

---

First, the simple case, no indirect branching, this is a very simple architecture, or a naive code generator. It's likely to end up as something like:

```
code:   load r0, [k]         ; get value of k

        cmp  r0, 1
        jeq  @100            ; address of line 100

        cmp  r0, 2
        jeq  @102

        cmp  r0, 3
        jeq  @105
nojmp:                       ; carry on
```

---

A system with indirect branches could use a table:

```
tbl:    word @100, @102, @105

code:   load r0, [k]         ; get value of k
        decr r0              ; table lookup probably zero-based

        cmp  r0, 0           ; only use table for valid range
        jlt  nojmp
        cmp  r0, 2
        jgt  nojmp

        jmp  [tbl, r0]       ; indirect jump
nojmp:                       ; carry on
```

---

However, even a system without indirect branches could use a table with some trickery, such as pushing the return address from the table and just returning:

```
tbl:    word @100, @102, @105

code:   load r0, [k]         ; get value of k
        decr r0              ; table lookup probably zero-based

        cmp  r0, 0
        jlt  nojmp
        cmp  r0, 2
        jgt  nojmp

        load r0, [tbl, r0]   ; indirect load
        push r0              ; emulating indirect jump
        ret
nojmp:                       ; carry on
```

Comment: Another possibility is storing the address directly into the jump instruction. I don't think I've seen a compiler do that, but it certainly was common enough in machine code at one time.